# place google autocomplete address info on page, not in form

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I would like to display the City, State and Country (in format: City, State, Country) from an autocomplete on the page, but not in a form. As the user selects the autocomplete, I would like that info to display as they select it, as a sort of headline on the current page, not on a subsequent page.

Should I put separate Divs back to back with the Ids from the autocomplete?

Youll notice on this page, for example, as soon as you choose the autocomplete, your location is made into the 'headline' of the page instantly. http://latestweatheralerts.com/

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: please look at the addtional comment i added at the end of my query with the example.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs added demo code:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input); 
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace(); 
    //Now do something with the place object properties 
});
```

Comment: im not sure this addresses my query?

Comment: I used it before, it works. `places_changed` is called when you click an address from the dropdown. But then you'll need to add your own logic to set the header (which is just a custom dom element).